# Cricket Ruling - Run out after a short run

Tags: rules, cricket

I am looking for assistance on a scenario where

1. The 1st run was successfully compeleted by the batsman on non-striking end
2. 2nd run was short by the non-striking batsman
3. When the non-striking batsman ran for the 3rd run, the striking batsman got run out on the other end
4. The non-striking batsman who took short run, came back to his crease after the other batsman got run out on the opposite end.

Question: Will the 2nd run be considered as the player took short run initially but came back to crease when the other batsman got run out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your explanation correctly:

- The first run was properly completed
- The second run was run short by the non-striker
- The striker was run out going for the third run.

If it hadn't been for the short run, this would result in two runs scored and the striker being run out; however, due to the short run, only one run is scored - [Law 18](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/scoring-runs):

> 18.3.2 Although a short run shortens the succeeding one, the latter if completed shall not be regarded as short.
>
> [...]
>
> 18.4.1 if either batsman runs a short run, the umpire concerned shall, unless a boundary is scored, call and signal Short run as soon as the ball becomes dead and that run shall not be scored.

Therefore one run is scored, and the striker is out.

Comment: Will it be the same ruling even if the batsmen did not cross each other when they started running for the 3rd run?

Comment: If the batsmen haven't crossed for the 3rd run, the striker cannot be out at the non-striker's end, but ignoring that: yes. The batsmen have correctly completed one run so that's always going to be given, they've incorrectly completed one run so that's not going to be given, and someone is out.